# Segmentation fault when attemping to print NSString as UTF8String

Tags: objective-c, gnustep

I have the following objective-c snippet in my hello world example:

```
//hello.m

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "hello.h"

void sayHello()
{
    #ifdef FRENCH
    NSString *helloWorld = @"Bonjour Monde!\n";
    #else
    NSString *helloWorld = @"Hello World\n";
    #endif
    printf("%s", [helloWorld UTF8String]);
}


//main.m
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "hello.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    sayHello();
    return 0;
}
```

building this stuff on osx works fine and runs as expected. But when compiling/linking it on ubuntu (using GNUStep) results in an segmentation fault when executing the binary. I nailed it down to the casting operation in the printf statement, but I have no clue what I'm doing wrong here or how I can solve this.

Interesting note: This works fine when using gcc toolchain to build the executable. I just see this issue when building it with clang on ubuntu.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: by casting I meant this particular statement: "[helloWorld UTF8String]"

Comment: `[helloWorld UTF8String]` is a method call, not a cast. Please provide the rest of your code for context. What you have posted won't compile (no functions/methods, etc)

Comment: UTF8String returns a `const char*` version of the NSString.  It's existence is tied to the lifetime of the NSString object in a manner that could be easily mucked up if the storage management environment is even slightly corrupt.

Comment: The snippet above is all the code I'm trying to execute. So directly  after setting up the NSString, I call the printf statement. So from my humble point of view nothing should mucked up...

Comment: ObjC, like C, requires a `main()` function as its entry point. I'd think your code would fail to compile without that, rather than segfault, but I suppose it's possible that gcc compiles something which then falls over at runtime. Try putting this inside a `main()`.

Comment: I've updated my snippet. I have this code in a method which is called in a main() method. Compilation and linking works fine. just running results in the segmentation fault. using gdb I traced it down to *[helloWorld UTF8String]* statement

Comment: have you been through this tutorial for GNUstep? http://www.gnustep.it/nicola/Tutorials/WritingMakefiles/node6.html. Curious are you launching it using openapp? This doesn't seem like a code issue with your hello.m file to me.

Comment: thanks foggzilla. I've seen this tutorial, but I built an executable and not a whole app. By executing my executable as root, everything works fine, just as expected. Interesting note: It also workds when using gcc toolchain. I just see this issue when using clang on ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue, I ended up changing my code to the following:

```
...
void sayHello()
{
    #ifdef FRENCH
    NSString *helloWorld = @"${HELLO_WORLD_FRENCH}\\n";
    #else
    NSString *helloWorld = @"${HELLO_WORLD}\\n";
    #endif

    NSFileHandle *stdout = [NSFileHandle fileHandleWithStandardOutput];
    NSData *strData = [helloWorld dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    [stdout writeData: strData];
}
...
```